# creating a template (class) for smart diagram (bubble diagram)

Tags: smartdiagram

I'm trying to build a template for a bubble diagram, since I don't know in advance how many bubbles need to be added I'm trying to do it using foreach.

I suspect \foreach does not expand the way I think it would because instead of multiple bubbles I get 1 bubble with all the text.

```
\newcommand\addbubbles[1]{
    \foreach \x in {#1}{\textbf{\x}, \newline}
}

% Command for printing bubble
\newcommand\flexbubblediag[1]{
    \renewcommand{\flexbubblediag}{
        \smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{
            \addbubbles{#1}
        }
    }
}
```

in my .tex I use to

```
\flexbubblediag{{bubble1},{bubble2}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the expansion with foreach was unnecessary.

```
% Command for printing bubble
\newcommand\skillbubbles[1]{
    \renewcommand{\skillbubbles}{
        \smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{#1}
    }
}
```

Works just fine

```
% Skill bubbles 
\skillbubbles{{Skill1}, {Kill12}, {madSkill}, {mad \\ science}}
```